# AnyLogic: two customer classes having different priorities

Tags: anylogic, queueing

I know the basics of AnyLogic/Process Modeling Library and am about to teach simulation of basic queues with AnyLogic, transitioning from Simul8 that I 've used for many years.

I have agents of two types, 1 and 2, sent to respective queues 1 and 2, which then feed a single "service" point, so that type 1 takes higher priority (that is, whenever service is ready to pull work, it pulls from queue 1 if it is non-empty, regardless of the size of queue 2). How to capture this as simply as possible?

Having seen the reference pages for a Queue object, my preliminary (unworked) idea is to use a single queue, and control agent priority by the Queue.QUEUING_PRIORITY- Priority-based" option.

For comparison, a solution in the Simul8 software is: set "service" routing-in discipline to "priority"; and assign different priorities to the two queues.

Comment: you go it right... no need for 2 queues

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you cant use two queues as the pull from the queues will be done in a round robin fashion. See the screenshot below from the AnyLogic training textbook

[image]

You should use queueing in a single queue and you can have either a single parameterised source or two.

See example below

I have 2 sources and at each of them, I set the priority to a local variable inside my agent. Agents from source 1's variable is set to 1 and the from source set to 0.

[image]

Then inside the queue, I set the priority so that the agents from source 1 is always in front.

[image]